# Suppose that a coin is tossed repeatedly. What is the probability that the third head occurs before the fifth tail?

Tags: probability, statistics

> Suppose that a coin is tossed repeatedly. What is the probability that the third head occurs before the fifth tail?

I think this question can be solved using negative binomial but I'm not sure. Any suggestions?

Comment: If we throw until we have three heads, how does the total number of throws tell us whether there have already been (at least) five tails? Now use negative binomial. Alternatively, after how many throws are you guaranteed to know whether you succeeded or failed? How many sequences of throws have that length? How many of those sequences represent successes / fails?

Comment: After seven throws, you must have three heads, or five tails, but not both. So the probability of three heads in seven throws...?

Comment: So would solving this question using binomial distribution with n = 7 and p = 0.5 work if I solve for P(X = 3)?

Comment: @user478136 Close, but not entirely. You could have $X = 4$, and it would also represent a win. Or $5, 6$ or $7$. I would suggest calculating the probability of a fail instead. That only covers $X = 2, X = 1$ or $X = 0$, so it's a shorter calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by noticing that to have $3$ heads before $5$ tails is the same as having at least $3$ heads among the first $7$ tosses.

So we just have a standard binomial with $n=7$ and $3 \leq k \leq 7$:
$$\sum_{k=3}^{7} \binom{7}{k} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{7-k} \approx .773 $$

Alternatively, you can make use of the negative binomial distribution.

$n$ trials, given $k$ success:
$${{n-1}\choose{k-1}}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

In our case, $n$ can be $3,4$, $5$, $6$ or $7$ and $k$ is fixed at $3$. Thus we have

$${2\choose{2}}\frac{1}{2}^3\frac{1}{2}^0+{3\choose{2}}\frac{1}{2}^3\frac{1}{2}^1+{4\choose{2}}\frac{1}{2}^3\frac{1}{2}^2+{5\choose{2}}\frac{1}{2}^3\frac{1}{2}^3+{6\choose{2}}\frac{1}{2}^3\frac{1}{2}^4 \approx .773$$

Comment: Note your $.773\ldots$ is $\dfrac{99}{128}$